# create variables in base workspace - from function calling script

Tags: matlab

In my loadsignals.m script has a function which runs a script test.m to create variables in base workspace.

Why variables are not created in base workspace ?

How can i create variables in base workspace I do not want to use assignin function ?

loadsignals.m :--

```
function loadSignals(VarName)

  ... do some work ...

  run(test);

end
```

test.m :--

```
a = uint8(10);
b = uint8(20);
c = uint16(0);
```

Comment: You call the script from a function, the variables have the functions scope. You already have a solution (`assignin`), what is wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a script from a function, the script uses the function workspace. Therefore the created variables are not stored in the base workspace unless you do it explicitly. This can be done with `assignin` as already mentioned.

One reason of not using `assignin` could be that you don't want to modify the script `test.m` itself. To circumvent this, you can use `evalin` to execute `test.m` in the base workspace. The variables are then getting stored in the base workspace as well.

```
evalin('base','run(''test.m'')');
```

*Note that `run(test)` may not work because the file `test.m` is a script and not a function. You can use `run('test.m')` instead. To have the `'` in a string, you need to write it twice `''` like shown in the second argument of `evalin`.*